# Can bounds checking be disabled in Java/Scala?

Tags: java, arrays, scala, memory-management, jvm

We know that Java, on each array element access, checks if the index is not out of bounds. But in some cases, such as map functions in Scala, the compiler/library would be handling the indexes by its own, thus guaranteeing no out of bounds accesses.

So, for performance reasons, can such bounds checking be disabled in the JVM for some parts of the code?

Comment: bounds checks are rarely the actual performance bottleneck since it gets heavily optimized (loop-hoisted at a minimum). If you have done instruction level profiling to confirm that it actually is the case then you could consider to use `Unsafe` to bypass the checks. But to my knowledge none of the JDK classes do something like that, only a few 3rd-party high performance libs might.

Comment: @the8472 JDK does use the Unsafe a lot, e.g. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#l3243  And it was intended to be only use, but then 3rd-party libraries also seized Unsafe.

Comment: @Kan CHM uses unsafe for concurrency (atomic accesses to fields), we're talking about using unsafe to bypass bounds checking in arrays

Comment: @the8472 Whatever, see ArraySupport class then, it is used by `java.util.Arrays` https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev/blob/master/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArraysSupport.java#L124 , also nio `XxxBuffer` rely on Unsafe a lot. The public API just wraps Unsafe methods with additional checks to make it safe.

Comment: @kan none of those listed examples use Unsafe for the sole purpose of bypassing bounds checks. The vectorized mismatch does it to get longs out of non-`long[]` arrays. The bytebuffers perform their own bounds checks anyway and may access native memory instead of arrays.

Comment: @the8472 Sounds like a wishful thinking. They use the `vectorizedMismatch` for `long[]` arrays too. The purpose of the method is to gain performance by doing unchecked access to array in a tight loop. If you are not convinced enough, there is another place when they tell about range checks explicitly: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.desktop/share/classes/sun/java2d/marlin/MarlinCache.java#l332 (comment for the constant is _do AA range checks: disable when algorithm / code is stable_)

Comment: @kan they're using unsafe to access off-heap data there, you always have to do offset calculations there manually. This discussion is about accessing *java arrays* (i.e. on-heap) via Unsafe and not doing any bounds checks at all to eliminate that tiny cost of, well, doing bounds checks. Normally the compiler is quite good at hoisting those out of loops anyway, that's why there are very few cases where such an optimization is needed and I don't think you will find one in the JDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, array range checks can't be disabled.  That would be make the JVM unsafe.

However, the JIT compiler may be able to infer that certain range checks are unnecessary and optimize them away.

Also, it is possible that the JIT compiler does "clever things" for certain builtin types.  You can side-step the issue by implementing stuff in native code, though you may then find that the overheads of making a native call swamp the savings of doing the computation natively.

---

> Can you maybe show some example code, where JIT **would** infer no bounds checking is required?

Not without some spending more time than I'm willing to :-)

However, a JIT compiler *could in theory* infer that no array bounds checks are needed here:

```
  public int sum(int[] array) {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          sum += array[i];
      }
      return sum;
  }
```

And in this case, simple peephole optimization should eliminate the 2nd bounds check in the loop body:

```
  public int sum2(int[] array) {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          sum += array[i];
          sum += array[i];
      }
      return sum;
  }
```

Comment: Can you maybe show some example code, where JIT would infer no bounds checking is required?